# Running "patch" without generating *.orig and *.rej files

Tags: linux, source, patch

Is it possible to tell `patch` not to generate `.orig` and `.rej` files?
I find it extremely annoying that patch creates these.

Answer (score 19):

If you're not giving any option to `patch` other than `-pN`, it only creates those files when a patch fails to apply cleanly.

So, one option is to stop creating (or accepting) bad patches. :)

Back in the real world, this is a feature. When `patch(1)` fails to apply a patch segment to the original file, it saves the temporary original file copy out durably as `*.orig`, dumps the rejected segment to `*.rej`, and continues trying to apply patch segments. The idea is that you can open the `*.rej` file and complete the patch process manually by copying bits and pieces over to the patched file. The `*.orig` file can also be useful when the patch process accidentally wrecks something, and you need to refer to the original version to fix it.

I don't always fix a bad patch with text from the `*.rej` and `*.orig` files, but it's nice to have them in case I need them.

Once I've fixed up a bad patch, I run the following script at the project root to quickly clean things up:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . '(' \
    -name \*-baseline -o \
    -name \*-merge -o \
    -name \*-original -o \
    -name \*.orig -o \
    -name \*.rej \
')' -delete
```

I call it `cleanup-after-bad-patch` because the long name partially insures against running this accidentally, since it could remove files you still need. To be honest, though, I normally run it by typing `clean`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, that being sufficient to find this script in the `PATH` on my development machines.

The additional patterns it checks for are for the files output by [my version control system of choice](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) when it encounters the same problem during a merge operation. You may wish to adjust it for your [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)/[SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) tools.

Comment: Easier is to not create the backup files with option `--no-backup-if-mismatch`. This can be combined with `--merge` to create inline merge info instead of .rej file.

Comment: @mihca: That option was added in [`patch` 2.4](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/tree/NEWS), prior to the software's adoption as a GNU project, so it's probably "everywhere" by now, but only within the world that uses GNU `patch`, rather than some other version. Per that same reference, another way around this issue is to set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable, but beware that this affects many tools other than GNU `patch`: `bash`, `grep`, and more.

Answer (score 10):

The `--no-backup-if-mismatch` option will avoid the ".orig" files.

You might also want to try the `--merge` option, which creates an in-file conflict.

In all cases you should have some way to get back to a good state quickly if the merge becomes overwhelming.

Answer (score 8):

To tell patch not to produce backups just omit the `-b` and any `--backup-...` options.

To instruct it not to create `.rej` files add `-r -` option to the command.

Comment: This doesn't work for me – it just puts the rejects in a file called "-", which is a very very annoying filename to have around. I'm using version 2.5.8 on a Mac.

Comment: working ok on `GNU patch 2.6` on mac perhaps try `-r /dev/null`

Comment: `-r /dev/null` doesn't work. `saving rejects to file /dev/nullpatch: **** Can't remove file /dev/null : Operation not permitted`

Comment: Since I see no way to get it to not output a rej file (on the default Mac version), I have simply resorted to dumping the file to /tmp. `--reject-file=/tmp/rej`

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck with patch v2.5.4 where `-r -` causes it to create reject files named `-`.

I found that `--reject-file=` i.e. empty value causes patch to fail with exit code `2` **IF** it tries to write a reject file. If there are no rejects it works as expected. While not a complete solution for older version of patch, under some circumstances this may be acceptable or desired.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with (admittedly a way to sweep the dirt under the rug) is using `-r <tmpfile>`, i.e.:

`# patch -r /tmp/deleteme.rej -i patchfile filetobepatched`

since in v2.5.8, `-r -` actually creates the `-` file.

Comment: Unsatisfying, but this is the best solution out of all the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the undocumented `--version-control none` option. That option is [documented for the FreeBSD variant of `patch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=patch).

Answer (score 0):

Use patch -NC to check if a patch will apply forwards cleanly, and only apply the patch if the check succeeds:

```
patch -NC /path/to/mypatch.diff && patch /path/to/mypatch.diff
```

Answer (score -3):

patch -p1 -B /dev/null -r - < file.patch

Comment: -1: This is very bad advice. First, the `-B` flag doesn't send the `*.orig` output to `/dev/null`, as it appears to from your command. It just happens that normal users can't write to files called things like `/dev/nullfoo.cpp`. If you do this as root, you'll get junk in your `/dev` tree instead. Second, `-r -` doesn't suppress the `*.rej` file. It just appears to do that because the error due to the bogus `-B` flag stops it from showing you what it *really* would do without the `-B`, which is create a file called `-` in the current directory.

Comment: @WarrenYoung according to `man patch`: "-r Put rejects into rejectfile instead of the default .rej file.  When rejectfile is -, discard rejects."